# why css break (not taking the height of li)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ionic-framework

I try to make one simple demo  using this [link](http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/create-breadcrumb-navigation-with-css3/)
I am able to make this as understand better 
here is [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdmYBv) But when I integrate it my application it break .Mean display half (in form of cut pieces ) .why ? CSS is not applied in that 
Actually my breadcrumb not display as it display in my demo .I think ionic css is conflict  my style css can we make this demo with ionic ? how to resolve this issue ?

here is my live application [demo url](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpGyNG)

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

```
#my-breadcrumbs ul li {
        list-style:none;
    }

    #my-breadcrumbs {
        margin-top: 44px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    #my-breadcrumbs ul li a {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        background: grey;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 22.5px 0 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }


    #my-breadcrumbs ul li a:after {
        content: "";
        border-top: 20px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
        border-left: 20px solid grey;
        position: absolute; right: -20px; top: 0;
    }


    #my-breadcrumbs ul li a:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;

        margin-top: -15px;
        border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: grey grey grey transparent;
        left: -20px;
    }


    /* Hide the Before Pseudo Element */
    #my-breadcrumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
        display: none; }

    /* Add Border Radius */
    #my-breadcrumbs ul li:first-child a{
     border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#my-breadcrumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 13px;  //Add this
  height: 40px;  //Change this
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 22.5px 0 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

If you wantmargin between each links change `margin: 0 22.5px 0 0;` to  `margin: 0 30px 0 0;`

Comment: why ? why it is not working for 25px height and can we give some margin between that ..li ? one element to another elemnt

Comment: @PallaviSharma it is because you added ionic.css link it is taking some property from that css file

Comment: ok ..I undertand that but it not look good if height is 40px .if you look at my demo  it look and perfect when I take 25 px..Secondly  I also use another way tp make same thing with different way ..please see this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNPGYe .I added some margin in it using this property  margin-left  ..can we add some margin in this  ?

Comment: @PallaviSharma Ok use  line-height: 13px; and i have updated my answer as well.

Comment: can we add margin as I said can add space between the elemnt ?

Comment: In the same example if you change 22.5px margin to 30px you will get what you want